# When I click on a FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) notification, the application restarts

Tags: android, firebase, messaging

Every time I receive a notification sent through the FCM console and I press it, instead of starting the application in the background state, it launches my Main activity, which in this case is a login. I have implemented my service class and so I have called it in the Manifest of my application:

```xml
<service
     android:name=".utils.FirebasePushNotificationsService"
     android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Then in my FirebasePushNotificationsService class I just overwrote the onMessageReceived method, so that when I'm in the foreground, I launch a Toast:

```kotlin
class FirebasePushNotificationsService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            Toast.makeText(
                baseContext,
                remoteMessage.notification?.body,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    }
}
```

And in the Manifest file I have my activities like this:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".views.DashboardActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing" />

<activity
    android:name=".views.SmartphoneActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

<activity
    android:name=".views.CustomActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

<activity
    android:name=".views.LoginActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The first activity that starts is the LoginActivity and then navigates to the DashboardActivity, and if being in this activity, I put the app in the background, when I receive the notification and I press it, it sends me to the LoginActivity again... I've tried to set the launchMode, but it didn't work or I didn't know how to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

add click action in firebase console during creating notification and add an intent filter in DashboardActivity in the manifest.[image: firebase console compose notification]

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="open_dashboard_activity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```